# Precipitation Totals past days online?

Tags: meteorology, precipitation

I am looking for a website that can I look for to check and see the precipitation totals for past days..

I go to this site : https://www.cocorahs.org/ . It lacks in some areas where I live in the rural areas...

Are there sites that can I find that are hard to find areas like where I live ?

Location is Pueblo West, Colorado. There are some areas that received totals in Pueblo.

I have gone to The Weather Channel , WU, etc...but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

One of the best sites I know of for this type of analysis is the National Weather Service’s [precipitation analysis site](https://water.weather.gov/precip), which combines radar data, gauge observations, and satellite data to make an informed analysis over the entire country, not just where there are rain gauges.

You can use the controls below the map to choose day(s) for which you’d like to see the precipitation analysis, and it looks like they have archived data going back to 2005. I don’t know offhand if you can quickly get exact totals from the site, but it should be enough for a rough idea.

And if you’re more specifically interested in snow totals (instead of liquid precipitation), there’s also [another site](https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/nsa/) from the NWS dedicated to snowfall analyses.

Comment: You could also check out http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/janowiak/cmorph_description.html for CMORPH data, which is a satellite derived rainfall product widely used in research (e.g https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/10.1175/1525-7541%282004%29005%3C0487%3ACAMTPG%3E2.0.CO%3B2).